# Colored balls puzzle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

Imagine you have $n$ balls in a bag that are colored from $1$ to $n$.  At each turn you take two balls at random out that have *different* colors and color one the color of the other. You then put them both back in the bag.  What is the expected number of turns before all the balls have the same color?

Comment: How do I choose which to repaint?  Is it random?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: For $n \ge 3$, it can potentially take an infinite number of turns. Are you looking for the probability to do it all in one very lucky streak? In the best case, you need $(n - 1)$ turns.

Comment: What distribution are you using to select your two balls? Note that "uniformly select over all pairs of different-colored balls" and "pick a ball at random, then pick another ball at random whose color is different from the first one" are inequivalent...

Comment: @Micah It should be "uniformly select over all pairs of different-colored balls".

Comment: Simulations for small $n$ suggest that the correct answer is $\binom{n}{2}$ (and this is certainly right for $n \leq 3$), but I don't have a proof.

Comment: The answer is $\binom{n}{2}$, see [this discussion on mathoverflow][1].


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130489/another-colored-balls-puzzle

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have $a$ balls of colour 1, $b$ balls of colour 2 and so on.
Let $F(a,b,c)$ be the expected number of turns until they reach uniformity.
Then from small values, it looks like
$$F(a,b) = ab\\
F(a,b,c)=ab+ac+bc$$
from which I generalize to $\sum_{i<j}a_ia_j$.  This confirms $n$ choose $2$ as the answer to your question.
EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see @azimut's comment; the Gambler's Ruin argument gives a simple proof of this formula.